# short/fast/elegant js to get an array of all css property names

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I just came over the problem to get an array of all available css properties like:

```
['top',… , 'right', … ]
```

I know it can be done in such a way:

```
var a = document.createElement('a'),
    s = a.style, r = [], p;

for (p in a.style) {
    r.push(p) //only if own property…
}
```

But I am searching for an elegant way in such a manner like that one to convert `arguments` or `Nodelists`to an array:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

or getting the maximum Number from an array:

```
Math.max.apply(null, [1,5,3,4]);
```

I have tried some stuff and the one below worked on Firefox:

```
Object.keys(document.body.style.__proto__);
```

**BUT NOT IN** chrome and I have not tested with any other browser yet…

Comment: Is there a certain reason why you don't want to use the drop-dead simple five-line approach that you have an that apparently works?

Comment: I posed the question because I want know if such an elegant »one-liner« exists and if yes, if its faster in execution.

Comment: If you're deadset on Object.keys, just use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), although I'm not sure which version of Chrome, as it understands Object.keys, in your case `Object.keys( document.body.style )` works fine. I've no idea if its a good idea though.

Comment: This smells like premature optimization to me. I have a very hard time imagining that *this* is the performance bottleneck of your application.

Comment: @Matt Styles `Object.keys( document.body.style )` gives me an emtpy array in FF but works in Chrome…

Comment: Performance is secondary for me, in this case code style matters most :)

Comment: @philipp yeah, was wondering that. if code style is important, why do you want a one-liner? they're often unreadable and sometimes confusing, if code style is important your five liner makes your intention explicitly clear with just a glance.

Comment: I second Matt (you might have guessed that). Don't write "smart" code when you can avoid it. Code golf is not for production code.

Comment: All in all, it's just about code style… I like good oneliners! I will remove `css` from the tags…